# How to write commit message to svn repository

Tags: apache, svn, webdav, jackrabbit

I am using Apache Jackrabbit Webdav library for svn checkin operation.

I am using MAKActivity method to start the transaction.

But I dont know how to add commit message. Following is the code

```
RandomStringGenerator rsg = new RandomStringGenerator(32);
String random = rsg.nextString();
String url = getRepoAddress() + "!svn/act/" + random;
MkActivityMethod activityMethod = null;
try
{
    activityMethod = new MkActivityMethod(url);
    client.executeMethod(activityMethod);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code executes successfully but I dont unserstand how to write log message in this.
Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'd suggest that you not reinvent the wheel that's already been done twice now and instead using a library that knows Subversion's DAV based protocol.  Note that while Subversion is mostly WebDAV and DeltaV compatible, it does have non-standard extensions.

To that end I'd point you to [JavaHL](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/javahl/latest/) or [SVNKit](http://www.svnkit.com).  JavaHL comes with Subversion and uses JNI to access the Subversion libraries.  SVNKit is an independent Java only implementation and includes a couple different interfaces, including one that is JavaHL compatible.  If the use of the native libraries by JavaHL doesn't present a problem for you I'd recommend this since you'll have the benefit of using the same libraries as nearly every Subversion client.

If however your goal is to understand how Subversion implements the protocol on top of WebDAV and DeltaV then perhaps you want to just use a generic WebDAV and DeltaV client library to help.  I'd recommend that you refer to these [documents that describe how WebDAV and DeltaV are implemented within Subversion](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/).

One thing you might want to understand is that [as of Subversion 1.7 we support what we refer to as HTTPv2](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#httpv2).  HTTPv2 varies somewhat from the DeltaV standard in particular.  Instead of using `MKACTIVITY` to start a transaction on the server we use a `POST`.  Which has a body with a syntax something like this:

```
(create-txn)
```

or

```
( create-txn-with-props (PROPNAME PROPVAL [PROPNAME PROPVAL ...])
```

The older style which you must use with `MKACTIVITY` (and can use with the `POST` if you use `create-txn` instead of `create-txn-with-props`) is to use a `PROPPATCH` on the transaction or the working baseline URL.

The working baseline URL is used with `MKACTIVITY` and the transaction URL is used with the POST.

When using `MKACTIVITY` you have to use a `PROPFIND` on the root URL to get the `version-controlled-configuration`.  Then do a `CHECKOUT` against the URL you received in response to that `PROPFIND` providing the `activity-set` `href` as the URL you used with `MKACTIVITY`.  You'll get the working baseline URL back as the `Location` header from the CHECKOUT request.  Which you can then use to issue a `PROPPATCH` to apply the revision properties.

When using `POST`, you get the transaction stub from the headers in the `OPTIONS` request response, the transaction name from the `SVN-Txn-Name` header in the response to the `POST`, and execute a `PROPPATCH` against the `$transaction_stub/$transaction_name` URL.

Probably the best ways to figure all this out is to setup a Subversion server and do some commits while running Subversion through a debugging proxy server such as [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).  You can force the traffic through the proxy on the svn command line with these options `--config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port=8888 --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=127.0.0.1`.  If you want to see the old protocol you can include `SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol off` in your http configuration.

In order to support the broadest range of Subversion servers you need to implement the HTTPv1 protocol, which has more round trips and is more difficult to implement.  If you want to only implement HTTPv2 you'll be limited to supporting Subversion servers newer than 1.7.  In order to use HTTPv2 with maximum compatibility you'll have to detect the presence from the `OPTIONS` response.

As you can see it gets rather complicated so it's really not worth trying to write your own client if all you want to do is implement some basic functionality.

Comment: Hi Ben thank you very much for your reply. I appreciate your knowledge regarding subversion.
I know that the best way to implement subversion is to use readymade libraries like svnkit and javahl. In fact we were using the svnkit library in out products old versions. But then this library is not free. And due to same reason we are implementing functionality using apache webdav jackrabbit library.

Comment: I understood whatever you mentioned here partially and if I am not wrong I have 2 options to write log message
a) Use MKACTIVITY, PROFIND to CHECKOUT and After CHECKOUT I need to use PROPATCH to apply revision props.
b) Use POST method along with PROPATCH.
Please let me know am I right?
If I am right then I will prefer option b) using POST method along with PROPATCH.
I tried searching on this on google but unable to get sample code for this.
Can you give me some sample code to implement this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirements are but if you want to support older Subversion (pre 1.7) servers you have to support MKACTIVITY.  There are a lot of servers without the v2 protocol support. If you don't care about that then yes you can use POST.  The POST method is not related at all to DAV and so I have no idea how much luck you will have with getting your DAV library to execute that for you .  I presume you know this but JavaHL is free (I'm guessing that the JNI is the issue for you).  I'm not in a good position to write sample code for you.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to do a SVN commit using WebDAV via the SVNAutoversioning on directive?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.webdav.autoversioning.html

AFAIK, the spec does not allow you to provide a commit message and the server will always create one for you.  Perhaps you want to look at the SVNKit library if you are trying to create SVN transactions via Java.

http://svnkit.com

Comment: Actually he's not depending on autoversioning if he's using MKACTIVITY (which is part of the DeltaV protocol).  Autoversioning exists to allow DAV clients that don't know about DeltaV to be able to commit changes to a DeltaV (e.g. Subversion) capable server.  We recently had a request to support setting commit messages via autoversioning.  I declined this request because it doesn't make sense for an autoversioning client to be specifying a commit message when it's not even supposedly aware that the server is versioning.